# Need URL of umbraco site with aspx extension

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco5, umbraco-blog

I am new to Umbraco so please forgiven me if the question is simple.

My web site has url like **http://www.abc.com** & **http://www.abc.com/employee** etc., How can I get the root aspx file. I mean how can I call those URL using .aspx extension.

If HomePage template is responsible for http://www.abc.com I need something like http://www.abc.com/HomePage.aspx.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the site uses .aspx extensions or folder type extensions is set up in web.config.

You probably have a key of the following set:

add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true"

Which you need to change to "false"

Comment: Already it was false. Want I want to know now is, does Umbraco follow both .aspx extension and folder type extension. If yes how to get the .aspx url.

Comment: Umbraco follows both so calling /employee or /employee.aspx or /employee/ would all result in the same page being displayed.  So just add on .aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. /employee.aspx is working same as /employee. But how do I access the home page http://www.abc.com with extension

Comment: If you go to the homepage in the 'Content' section, switch to the properties tab, the name of the homepage will be at the top - to that and replace any spaces with dashes and add .aspx.